# Create Procedure/function for z-score

Tags: mysql

I planned to create a stored procedure (or function) to calculate student's z-score in a particular Maths Test `ma`. I wrote something like this but it still doesn't work. I wonder what could be the problem? And will there be some simpler ways to find z-score of a column in a click? Thanks!

```
PROCEDURE `zscore`(col VARCHAR(10) , tbl_name VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
WITH tbl_mean_std as (
    SELECT avg(tbl_name.col) m, stddev(tbl_name.col) sd FROM tbl_name
    )
SELECT
    (tbl_name.col-m)/sd AS zs
FROM tbl_name, tbl_mean_std;
END
```

Comment: Mysql will not substitute the table and column with the parameter names You need dynamic sql to do this see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: *`FROM tbl_name, tbl_mean_std`* Bad style, use CROSS JOIN. *`col VARCHAR(10) , tbl_name VARCHAR(20)`* Object names limitation is VARCHAR(64) for both tablenames and column names.